# How to change a specific Button's background color programmatically?

Tags: codenameone

I have managed to figure out the basics of the `Theme` editor and set the basic values for the `Component`s I am interested in.

I am using `ComponentSelector` `Component`s across the application, so I am able to choose any `Component` easily.

Now, I want to change the background color of specific `Button`s in run time. What would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for a new app, you should use the `theme.css` file instead of the Theme editor.

Said that, changing the background color of specific `Button`s in run time using the `ComponentSelector` can be done in the following way.

Assume to have a `theme.css` containing:

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true;
}

Button {
    margin: 0.5mm;
    padding: 0.5mm;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}

Button-Red {
    cn1-derive: Button;
    background-color: red;
}

Button-Green {
    cn1-derive: Button;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Case of only one Button (note that I use the `.asComponent()` method to select only one Component, *even if it's not necessary in this case*):

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
Button myBtn = new Button("My fun button", "Button-Red");
hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(myBtn));
hi.show();

UITimer.timer(2000, false, hi, () -> {
    // this code changes the color of the button after two second
    ComponentSelector.$("Button-Red").asComponent().setUIID("Button-Green");
    hi.revalidate();
});
```

Case of multiple Buttons:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
Button myBtn1 = new Button("My fun button 1", "Button-Red");
Button myBtn2 = new Button("My fun button 2", "Button-Red");
hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(myBtn1));
hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(myBtn2));
hi.show();

UITimer.timer(2000, false, hi, () -> {
    // this code changes the color of the buttons after two second
    ComponentSelector.$("Button-Red").setUIID("Button-Green");
    hi.revalidate();
});
```

Of course you can use different ways to select the components you are interested to, according to the documentation: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/ComponentSelector.html

Comment: I will give it a try. I assume that the .css file is added through the "Add Data" menu of the editor.

Comment: I have activated css in Codename One settings but IntelliJ pops a message that I need IntelliJ Ultimate to use css files. Is there a workaround?

Comment: No, `theme.css` is already included in every Codename One Maven project and it's already activated. Read this blog post about the Maven structure of Codename One: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/maven-project-structure.html As you can read, CSS files are in `common/src/main/css` and projects are set to use CSS by default. You can edit the styles in `common/src/main/css/theme.css`.

Comment: You can use CSS with the free IntelliJ you just won't get highlighting and code completion to CSS which suck. I personally pay for Ultimate which is worth it for me but you can just edit the code without those things or use VS Code for the CSS file. Notice that editing dynamically (so styles change while the simulator is open) would work regardless of the editor you use.  If you're still using Ant you need to migrate to maven first, see the article on the maven migration tool

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Well, I just moved to IntelliJ. Upgrading to another version is to be decided in the future.
I noticed that when I activated the css option, the `theme.res` file disappeared. Is this normal and expected behavior?

Comment: The only directory with a `css` title is directly under the project root in my "Project" view.

Comment: It’s strange… but I never used IntelliJ. Why don’t you try to inspect files directly in the file manager of your operating system, instead than in your IDE? You can use any free or paid CSS editing tool.

Comment: @Spyros did the theme file disappear in Ant? In maven CSS should be the default but I'm not sure about project migrations. How did you do the migration? Did you create a new project?

Comment: Well, I do not see anything strange in all that, because the developer guide mentions that this is the place where it should be. Double checked. I do not really get why the css editor is relevant, but in any case, I do the initial css coding on notepad++ then transfer a copy on the actual IDE css file.